# Invoke lambda function from AWS cli

Tags: shell, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to call the AWS lambda function from cli by shell script. I want to send the current logged user name to lambda function as parameter.
This is the code I tried:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    user=$(whoami)
    echo "=START="
    echo "$user"
    aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name shell_lambda_invoke --region ap-south-1 --log-type Tail --payload '{"bashuser":"${user}", "InstanceId":"'i-0c4869ec747845b99'"}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke the lambda function using AWS CLI write the following code which works fine:
I am sending payload to this function with instance ID and user name as I needed this in lambda if you wan't to send anything other you can send other details as input in payload section.

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$(whoami)
echo Please Enter the InstanceId
read InstanceId
aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name wu_core_auto_start_stop_lambdainvoke --region us-east-1 --log-type Tail --payload '{"bashuser":"'"${user}"'", "InstanceId":"'"${InstanceId}"'"}' outputfile.txt
```

Comment: "wu_core_auto_start_stop_lambdainvoke" is the name of lambda function.

Answer (score 3):

Since Your bash variable is inside single quotes it won't get populated.

Test:

```
$ echo "${user}"
root
```

Your sample:

```
$ echo '{"bashuser":"${user}", "InstanceId":"'i-0c4869ec747845b99'"}'
{"bashuser":"${user}", "InstanceId":"i-0c4869ec747845b99"}
```

You need to interrupt quoting like this:

```
$ echo '{"bashuser":"'"${user}"'", "InstanceId":"'i-0c4869ec747845b99'"}'
{"bashuser":"root", "InstanceId":"i-0c4869ec747845b99"}
```

Comment: I want to get the user name in: I tried waht you shared but doesn't work command:    aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name shell_lambda_invoke --region ap-south-1 --log-type Tail --payload '{"bashuser":" ' "${user}" ' ", "InstanceId":"'i-0c4869ec747845b99'"}'

Comment: the code is working fine when I tried with putty the same code doesn't work with Juicessh application. I am self answering question have look at it and thanks for you help:)